# How to Perform 2 join operation on an Object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, join

```
const rows = [
    ["Name", "City", "Info"],
    ["name1", "city1", "some other info"],
    ["name2", "city2", "more info"]
];
let csvContent = rows.map(e => e.join(",")).join("\n");
```

Similarly how can I implement the same on an Object array for example

```
const rows = [
        {name:"FirstName", city:"City", info:"Info"},
        {name:"LastName", city:"City", info:"Info"},
    ];
```

Comment: `rows.map(e => Object.values(e).join(",")).join("\n")`

Answer (score 0):

First you can Array#reduce it, saving the `Object.keys` as the first header row, then creating the array structure. Finally map all that just like your first example.

```js
const rows2 = [{
    name: "FirstName",
    city: "City",
    info: "Info"
  },
  {
    name: "LastName",
    city: "City",
    info: "Info"
  },
];

let csvContent2 = rows2.reduce((b, a, i) => {
  if (i === 0) b.push(Object.keys(a))
  return b.concat([Object.values(a)]);
}, []).map(e => e.join(",")).join("\n")
console.log(csvContent2);
```

Comment: Tried this, rows.map(e => Object.values(e).join(",")).join("\n") and it works fine ,anyway thanks :)